# Numpy function 'block()' not found on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, raspberry-pi

I have tried to find a probable cause for a problem I am having but have not found anything that has resolved the issue.

The problem is that I am running python3 (Python 3.4.2 [GCC 4.9.1] on Raspbian linux) code on a raspberry Pi while making use of numpy.

All numpy functions worked previously without problems before, but now I started to make use of the function numpy.block(). It is raising an;

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'block' error.

The exact same code is working perfectly on my regular (Linux) workstation, although that is python version 3.4.3 [GCC 4.8.4].

As I am making extensive use of numpy functions, it seems odd to me one specific function cannot be found.

Here is some additional information:

- I am not making use of a virtual environment
- I have tried to uninstall and re-install the numpy libs on the Raspberry Pi, to no avail
- I do not have a file called numpy.py shadowing my code
- running numpy.test('full') returns no probable causes

Any idea on where to look for a solution or what to try next is very welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you checked the numpy version on both systems?

Comment: Check the docs for [`block`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.block.html#numpy.block) and they will tell you which version of numpy added this function. Then check whether your version is new enough. If not, you need to update if possible, or rewrite your code to work with old numpy if not. (If you’re using a Python version as old as 3.4.2, there’s a pretty good chance you’re using an equally old numpy, especially if you got it from, e.g., `apt-get python3-numpy`, or by inheriting a really old machine, etc.)

Comment: If it isn't present in your older version of `numpy`, you might be able extract a working copy from the `numpy.core.shape_base.py file of a newer version (or the github repository).  I don't think there's anything that's compiled or using 'advanced' features.

Comment: Thanks to all for your input. Indeed it was a numpy versioning issue. Issue resolved.